# How To Change gnome-terminal Start Size

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

How do I set the gnome-terminal startup size from cli, by use of the -geometry argument, or by some cli editing of the settings please?  Many notations in numerous help pages indicate that one can no longer make these changes, is that true?

Comment: Does `--save-config` `--load-config` suggest any solutions that will work for you? `gnome-terminal --load-config <configfile> Where <configfile> is a modified --save-config setting Geometry=80x24+0+0' for example -- which places the window at 0,0

Comment: gnome-terminal lost the --save-config option as "obsolete" somewhere before version 3.10.2, i.e ----- according to a superuser post.  This seems to be the answer all over the chatter, both gnome-terminal and konsole have deprecated the option of setting terminal size.  I should say that the --geometry switch Does succeed in sizing and locating some other apps, but Not the terminals.  If this is by design, apparently deprecated from base linux itself, perhaps the docs for all terminals should be updated to reflect the deprecation?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it does not work for you because you use the `-geometry` argument rather than the correct argument, `--geometry`? For example,

```
gnome-terminal  --geometry 120x30+200+0
```

works for me on Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: nohup gnome-terminal --geometry 30+40+136+76 &   is what is producing nothing but OS default tiled terminals starting at upper left corner of screen, on Ubu2004.  Similar problems on a Debian KDE Konsole try.  I have tried many variations of this command on both machines, no joy; where at first some resizing and relocation does occur, but strangely after twenty or so design cycles the OS reverts to only laying down default tiled shapes.  It appears Ubu uses columns and lines for the terminal sizing, and screen pixels for location; but Debs uses screen pixels for both, but hard to say.

Comment: And how does it work if you just use the command I provided?

Comment: Hi Vanadium, Thanks for your answers.  Unfortunately no, no combination of the --geometry x+- argument syntax provides accurate cartesian coordinate placement of any terminal app I have tried.  Other apps do better, but not terminals.  I have also tried every possible combination of the x+- syntax on the arguments, no joy; and the chatter shows use of x++ and all +++, none work.  This looks like what the chatter says, a case of quiet deprecation.

Comment: That is not what you asked? You asked about "set the gnome-terminal startup size from cli, by use of the -geometry argument, or by some cli editing of the settings please"

Answer (score 0):

To change the gnome-terminal startup size from the cli, you can use the following commands:

```
PROFILE=`gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | awk -F \' '{print $2}'`
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$PROFILE/ default-size-columns 120
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$PROFILE/ default-size-rows 30
```

To list all keys that can be changed from the cli, you can use this:

```
gsettings list-keys org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile
```